# Implementing class Fibonacci with a recursive method in Java

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

Here's a part of my code that is relevant to the problem solving

```
public long Recursiv(){
    Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci(this.getNumar());
    long fibnum;

    if(this.getNumar() == 0) return 0;
    if(this.getNumar() <= 2) return 1;
    else
        fibnum = (fibo.Recursiv()-1) + (fibo.Recursiv()-2);
        return fibnum;

}
```

It is part of the Fibonacci class that I've created which has a constructor, a getter and setter methods.

My goal is to implement and print even fibonacci numbers in the console
e.g. 2, 8, 34...etc.

In the main method, whenever I apply the method on the object I receive a java.lang.StackOverflowError message with the issue that the line which makes the assignment is the problem.

What should I do?

Comment: Run in the debugger, name methods starting with lowercase letters and post complete code examples.

Comment: What do you think this: `fibo.Recursiv()-1` is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation of the Fibonacci sequence can be done by implementing the method as follows.

```
public long Recursiv(int n)
{
    if (0 == n)
        return 0;
    else if (1 == n)
        return 1;
    else
        return this.Recursiv(n - 1) + this.Recursiv(n - 2)
}
```

However this would require changing of the method's signature.

*Edit:*

Apparently I've misunderstood the question a bit; the desired argument is given in the constructor and the method should use instances with smaller arguments for evaluation. The method could also be implemented as follows.

```
public long Recursiv()
{
    if(this.getNumar() == 0)
        return 0;
    if(this.getNumar() <= 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return new Fibonacci(this.getNumar() - 2).Recursiv()
             + new Fibonacci(this.getNumar() - 1).Recursiv();
}
```

Comment: True, I was attempting to do it without the input, I was wondering if there is another way.

Comment: No worries, that's interesting so basically at the return it is creating new instances of the Fibonnacci class, am I right?

Comment: Yes, this apparently works, but it is a rather complicated way of doing the evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

You need a method that calculates the *nth* fibonacci number and returns the result — so you have to *tell* it which number in the fibonacci sequence you want.
That requires a parameter.

```
public long fib(int n) {
    ...
}
```

Now a fibonacci number is the sum of the two previous fibonacci numbers; that is

```
fib(6) = fib(5) + fib(4)
// or more generally
fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

so (without writing the whole thing for you) your method needs to *accept* and *pass* the necessary parameters:

```
public long fib(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    //  etc. -- handle the defined/degenerate cases
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
}
```